# SQL express 2008 restore from a SQL Server 2008 backup

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I have done some research online but i cant seem to find a proper answer.
I am trying to restore a SQL server 2008 backup onto a sql express 2008 system (Live environment backup to Development environment)

The problem is i keep getting a "SQL Server cannot process this media family" error code 3241.

Any ideas???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to create a script of the DB and then run it on an empty database of the same name.

Ref: http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40531